# SQL View + foreach not looping through results

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, foreach

I have a view that is returning a resultset LEFT OUTER JOIN from a SQL Database.  I'm using MVC 3 to display a partial view based on the resultset.  But....

```
@foreach (var category in Model.FeeScheduleRates().Distinct())
{
     <tr><td colspan="2">@category.Category</td></tr>
     foreach (var item in Model.FeeScheduleRates()
                               .Where(i=>i.Cat_ID == category.Cat_ID))
     {                               
         <tr> 
             <td>@item.Fee_Title - @item.Description</td>
             <td>@item.Amount</td>                                        
         </tr>
     }                                   
}
```

The view isn't looping through the second foreach loop.  Rather, it repeats the first entry as many times as there are matching records.  So it should create a table with a row spanning two columns for each category, and then display the items in that category (Title, Description and amount.

Why doesn't the second foreach loop work?

EDIT:  As requested The View

```
SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT a.Cat_ID, a.Fee_Title, a.Description, a.Amount, b.Category
FROM     dbo.Fee_Schedule AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.Fee_Categories AS b ON a.Cat_ID = b.Cat_ID
ORDER BY a.Cat_ID
```

Comment: Are you sure the view is returning what you think it is?  Can you post the view code?

Comment: are you absolutely certain it is not your data set that has the duplicated records like that. have you verified it in your controller before you are passing it to the view? I see nothing incorrect with your foreach loops, that is why i am inclined to look at the data being passed to the view.

Comment: The Controller creates a new RateViewer object:<br />

           `public virtual IEnumerable<FeeListing> FeeScheduleRates()
        {            
            var data = pubDB.FeeListings;
            return data.ToList();
        }`
<br /> which is just calling the view as an Entity Object FeeListings.<br /><br />Unless the Entity Framework is somehow borking out the view, the view looks golden in SQL Query viewer.